# Mediation through multiple regression when you have 2 or more than 2 IVs

Tags: regression, spss, mediation

I have 4 IVs 1 MV and 1 DV. The literature i have gone through to test mediation through path analysis (SPSS) only illustrate inclusion of 1 IV 1 MV and 1 DV. Is it possible to first check undertake the regression of MV on all 4 IVs then Regress DV on MV, followed by regressing DV on all 4 IVs and finally entering all 4 IVs and 1 MV to look for possible relation with DV?

Where i am confused is that do i need to individually check mediation (MV) between each individual IV and DV or i can do it all in an order explained above.
Really confused :(
Thanks a Lot in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do various things here, depending on your goals.  Which model you test should depend on what your hypotheses and research questions and goals are, but it is possible to have multiple mediation models.

Questions about how to do something in a particular program are off topic here, but David MacKinnon has written both a book on mediation analysis (*Introduction to Statistical Mediation Analysis*) and programs to run various models, including in SPSS.